# Prove one prime occurring to at least the t-th power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for all pairs of positive integers s and t, there are infinitely many
sequences of s consecutive positive integers, each of which, when factored
into prime powers, has at least one prime occurring to at least the t-th
power.

First, the question itself is difficult for me to understand what I need to show.

My understanding is that there is a set of s consecutive numbers, say {$a_1,a_2,...a_s$} and we take the prime factorization for each of them. Let $a_1=p_{1}^{e_{1}}p_{2}^{e_{2}}...p_{k}^{e_{k}}$..., and $a_s=p_{1}^{e'_{1}}p_{2}^{e'_{2}}...p_{k}^{e'_{k}}$. Suppose $p_1$ is the prime we want, we show that the power of p is greater than or equal to t?

I might not on the right track, anyone can give a hint how to start with? Really appreciate for that !

Comment: as far as I understand the question, you want to show that there are infinitely many such sequences of numbers that, when factored into primes, have at least one prime to the power at least t.

Comment: Denoting by $\Bbb P$ the set of prime numbers, you need to show that for every $(s,t)\in\Bbb Z^2$, there are infinitely many sequences of positive integers $\{a_k\mid a_k=a+i\}_{k=1}^{k=s}$ where $a$ is some non-negative integer such that,

$$\forall~1\leq k\leq s~,\exists p_k\in\Bbb P~:~(p_k)^t\mid a_k$$

Comment: You may use the Chinese remainder theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem/)